# Is there a shortcut in Visual Studio 2013 that shows the definition pop up of the selected element?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

The pop up appears when you hover over an element:

[image: Definition pop up]

Is there a equivalent keyboard shortcut for this? (In Eclipse there is, it's F2).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. You can see it already if you hover it. Why a shourtcut could be needed for this? Isn't that easy _hovering_ rather than a shortcut?

Comment: To avoid grabbing the mouse to do so.

Comment: @Soner Not if you're navigating by keyboard.

Comment: @Soner If you've got nothing useful to say, just don't say anything.  There are people who work faster without using the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called [Quick Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/137ey1yz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) shortcut is <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

From visual studio menu: Edit->Intellisense->Quick info

Comment: +1 for saying which command it is. This helped me to find it on my keyboard layout. It happens to be Ctrl+K, I, but it won't be the same for everyone. It also means people can re-map it to their own preference.

Answer (score 1):

Try `(Control + K) + (Control + L)`.

It won't give a pop-up but, will highlight the description.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+k followed by Ctrl+i works fine on VS2013 Ultimate